# How to transfer only the vertex groups' names between two identical meshes?

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have to identical meshes. They have the same vertex groups; different names, same order and the weights from one mesh are a bit deformed. **I need to only transfer the vertex groups' names**. Is there a method to do it? Or there is another method to easily extract all the vertex groups' names from one mesh to a program like excel or notepad?

Comment: Something I don't understand: If you already have the same vertex groups, why tranfer the vertex groups names? If you want to remove the vertices from the groups you can select all the vertices and Remove From All Groups

Comment: Hi, the vertex groups are the same, but the weight painting, from the mesh that has the correct names, is a bit deform. I need to use the other mesh that has the cleaner weight painting but with the names from the first mesh. I can do it manually, but there is almost 200 vertex groups per mesh, and I need to do it in various meshes.